# MUnit unit tests for TraditionalForm formatting

Tags: formatting, testing-and-verification

I'm a strong proponent of unit tests and as such I'm using the MUnit framework from Wolfram Workbench on a regular basis. Many of the codes I'm working on also
use `TraditionalForm` formatting in order to make objects look nicer in the Mathematica notebooks. Some of the formatting,, rules are pretty complicated which means that it would be nice to have unit tests for them as well.

However, I don't see a simple way to implement unit tests to check the TraditionalForm output of particular expression. For example, let us look at

```
MyObject/:MakeBoxes[MyObject[x_,y_],TraditionalForm]:=
If[x===y,SuperscriptBox["\[Alpha]",1],SuperscriptBox["\[Alpha]",2]]
```

Now I would like to write two tests like (pseudocode):

```
Representation[MyObject[1,1]] === SuperscriptBox[\[Alpha],1]
Representation[MyObject[1,2]] === SuperscriptBox[\[Alpha],2]
```

The best thing I was able to come up with is

```
TraditionalForm[MyObject[1,1]] === TraditionalForm[SuperscriptBox[\[Alpha],1]//DisplayForm]
TraditionalForm[MyObject[1,2]] === TraditionalForm[SuperscriptBox[\[Alpha],2]//DisplayForm]
```

Which however still doesn't return `True`. When I run Mathematica kernel without the frontend I see that
both

```
TraditionalForm[MyObject[1,1]]
```

and

```
TraditionalForm[SuperscriptBox[\[Alpha],1]//DisplayForm]
```

evaluate to

```
//TraditionalForm= α^1
```

but for some reason Mathematica doesn't consider them to be equal.

Is there some handy function to output the `TraditionalForm` of `MyObject[1,1]` and `MyObject[1,2]` in
terms of `SuperscriptBox` and `\[Alpha]`?

Or may be there is some standard way to write unit tests for the `TraditionalForm` representation that I'm completely missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TraditionalForm` and `DisplayForm` are just "wrappers". If you look at `FullForm` of expressions compared in question, you'll see that although they look the same, internally they are represented differently:

```
MyObject /: MakeBoxes[MyObject[x_, y_], TraditionalForm] :=
    If[x === y, SuperscriptBox["α", 1], SuperscriptBox["α", 2]]

TraditionalForm[MyObject[1, 1]]
TraditionalForm[MyObject[1, 1]] // FullForm
(*
Out[3]//TraditionalForm=
    α^1
Out[4]//FullForm=
    TraditionalForm[MyObject[1, 1]]
*)

TraditionalForm[SuperscriptBox["α", 1] // DisplayForm]
TraditionalForm[SuperscriptBox["α", 1] // DisplayForm] // FullForm
(*
Out[5]//TraditionalForm=
    α^1
Out[6]//FullForm=
    TraditionalForm[DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["\[Alpha]", 1]]]
*)
```

If you want to compare box representation of expressions, you should explicitly convert them to boxes.

```
MakeBoxes[MyObject[1, 1], TraditionalForm] === SuperscriptBox["α", 1]
(* True *)

ToBoxes[MyObject[1, 1], TraditionalForm] === FormBox[SuperscriptBox["α", 1], TraditionalForm]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solves my problem!